# store double value with precision using spring model and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, model

I want to store a double value as 100.55 because it will store the price value. This project is spring mvc with hibernate connecting to mysql database. I was doing this by model as

```
@Column(name = "GRAND_TOTAL_AMOUNT",length=8,precision=2)
private Double grandTotalAmount;
```

not getting desired result. Suggest solutions ?

Comment: *not getting desired result* - What is your desired result and what are you getting instead?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your issue clearly, however, there is one mistake in your mapping. You should use `precision` and `scale` instead of length, as length is meant for string values, so you should change to

```
@Column(name = "GRAND_TOTAL_AMOUNT", precision=8, scale=2)
private Double grandTotalAmount;
```

Note also that, when dealing with money BigDecimal is the preferred type over double. The mapping can remaing the same

```
@Column(name = "GRAND_TOTAL_AMOUNT", precision = 8, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal grandTotalAmount;
```

Check this blog to learn more https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_need_for_bigdecimal

Comment: I have tried your solution and not working on double. So i want to store currency value in double field like 100.99 But when i further do some division and then store it shows more then 2 places of decimal like 50.369852 I want that it should store value as 50.37 by default. Is it possible with double?

Comment: if you fix your mapping to use precision and scale, you can do it with either  double or BigDecimal, but you need to round it before persisting, the easiest would be to add the rounding logic to a setter e.g. public void setGrandTotalAmount(BigDecimal decTest) {
    this.decTest = decTest.setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
} or the equivalent for double. Then your decimal format should be consistent